# How does CPanel create subdomains?

Tags: subdomain, cpanel

I obviously know how to create subdomains via CPanel but does anyone know what exact method CPanel uses to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The server's [WHM configuration](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/NameserverSelect) allows cPanel to utilize either BIND or NSD as its DNS daemon: when a cPanel user adds a subdomain, corresponding DNS records are created in BIND or NSD.

Comment: I have no idea what BIND or NSD is guess I'll have to look into them. Many thanks for your answer

Comment: @aciid In the interest of familiarizing with the technologies behind cPanel, you might want to read up on [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) and [virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_host) - then you can read about the [daemons used by cPanel](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/ServiceMgr)